# do not create web site folder in the iiis of front end server but created in the iis of index server at sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

pls give me any suggestion ...

i create a new web application in the sharepoint 2007 ...

but web site folder are not created in the iis of front end server

but created in the iis of the index server ...

i need to appear web site folder in the iis of the front end server ...

pls give me any suggestion ...

thanks,

MTH83

Answer (score 0):

Go the Central Administrator. Select the Web Front End server's Services on Server.

Ensure that Web Application Service is started. The moment you do it, the Web Sites will be replicated on the WFE.

Comment: Web Application Service is aldreay started ... but timer job on the web front end server is failed ... it is because of "timer job fail at web front end server" ??  ...thanks a lot ...

Comment: yes, it could be because of timer job failing. Check the ULS Logs and try to find out why it is failing.